# ways to improve a glute/leg workout?

Tags: weightlifting, squats, legs

I am female, 145 pounds and 170cm tall.
I go to gym 4 times a week and do split training.
I have noticed quite some gains on my legs but not really my ass.
Here is my workout: (I am not sure of what weight I use, hence if I don't mention it... I don't know- but its heavy to the point where my 9th or 10th rep is basically impossible)

Seated leg press (100kg, 3 sets, 10 reps per set)

Squats (20kg- cant go up as I find it to hard to get the bar over my head, 3 sets, 10 reps per set)

Leg extension (3 sets, 10 reps)

Leg Press (5 sets, begin at 70kg and go up to 100kg and then back down again- is called doing a pyramid)

Then go onto do calves....

Is my butt just taking its time to grow? or are these exercises not adequately working my butt?

I get enough protein, sleep and nutrition :)

Comment: I'm confused by the statement that you can't increase your squats because you can't get the bar over your head.  Aren't you squatting out of a rack of some sort?

Comment: I'd ditch the machines and do standard squats/deads/cleans/ohp/bench type stuff, something like M/W/F. Toss in a yoga class if you want to get to 4 days a week. The isolation stuff and machines makes it much easier to get imbalances and injuries.

Answer (score 2):

Hip thrusts and glute bridges are glute (butt) specific. I suggest checking out [Brett Contreras aka The Glute Guy](http://bretcontreras.com/) for training advice based on both appearance and performance goals.

Comment: To a lesser extent, Romanian deadlifts and stiff legged deadlifts also help.  Those are more hamstring dominant though.

Answer (score 1):

Only the squats are heavily focused on your glutes, the others are more focused on quads, which would explain your gains on legs but not glutes.

How come you have to get the bar above your head to do squats? No squat rack or such?

I'd recommend squats or lunges with dumbbells to increase weight if you don't have a squat rack. There are also exercises that isolate the glutes that you could use, like standing hip extensions.

Answer (score 0):

**Deadlifting and Lunges are good go-tos for glute-development**

You can also look if your gym has a Roman Chair available:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_chair